# LinkedIn - Og image showing in Link Inspector, but not in posts

Tags: api, linkedin-api

When I post any blog post URL from my website to LinkedIn, the defined og image does not pull through: [see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbqqu.png)

However, when I view it in LinkedIn's post inspector it shows the image pulling through correctly: https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fwww.mvplogistics.com%2Fhow-logistic-companies-run-a-smooth-supply-chain-process%2F

Additionally, the og image DOES pull through correctly on Facebook: [see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcyGr.png)

Has anyone else run into this issue? What was your fix?

Comment: I do belive that this link might help you: [Linkdin not picking Open Graph Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769054/linkedin-not-picking-up-ogimage)